# Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is a code

```
var collection = (function (){
                var x = 0;
                return {
                    y : x,
                    get : function(){return x},
                    set : function(n) { x = n}                        
                }
              }());

collection.set(1000);
```

Why `collection.y != collection.get()` ?

Comment: you mean after you call "set(1000)" ?

Answer (score 8):

**y** is not a *"pointer"* to **x**. When created the closure you simply copied the value of **x** at that moment into **y**, and every time you call **get()**/**set()** you only operate on **x** (no relation to **y**)

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting collection y when you call collection.set(1000)

Answer (score 3):

Because **y** will store the value 0, and will **not** read it from **x**. While **get()** will read the variable **x** every time you call it.

Answer (score 3):

Well the object you're setting collection to looks like this:

```
{
  y : 0,
  get : function(){return x},
  set : function(n) { x = n}                        
}
```

there's no `x` property to store state in (edit: to be fair it will get created, but y still has a closure on the 0 value so won't be updated), so what else were you expecting? Replace x with y and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
function person(name,age){

    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;

    //closers
    this.sayHi=function(){

        return this.name+" say Hi"

    }

}

var p=new person("Ramesh",23);

alert(p.sayHi())
```